# Type conversion for multilanguage java

Tags: android, multilingual, decimalformat

My app supports **multi language**, i have a **problem** when dealing with **numericals**. Suppose my selected language is **hindi** and I perform some calculation operation on the value taken from edit text. I had to format the float value after the calculation (say like my resulting calculation **gives me 12.345678**) i will use the **decimal format class** to get only 12.34 (like only two digits after decimal point). Till here is fine, but i wanted the resulting string from decimalformat class( i.e: 12.34) **to be back as a float**. Here the crash happens stating **NumberFormatException**. Because the resulting **12.34 comes out as a hindi 12.34**
How can i **format the resulting calcution** (i.e: 12.3456) to 12.34 **without converting it to string**(i.e: decimalFormat.format(value)).

Comment: This makes no sense, formatting a number **does not** "destroy" it, so "store"/use etc the number and format only when you want to display it. Also note that there are locale aware `DecimalFormat`, so it's also possible to use one for display and another one for parsing

Comment: Ooh okay i will try with the locale available decimal format..Thanks for that. I ll update as soon as i do that exercise.

Comment: finally i am forced to follow this **"store"/use etc the number and format only when you want to display it**. Place your comment as an answer. Thank you @RC.

Comment: Hi there @RC. ,i dont want to apply hindi language change on numerical value how do i achieve this. My requirement is even If i change the language the numericals must not get affected.